# Retrieval augmented generation (RAG) for text classification

Tags: vector, huggingface-transformers, word-embedding, langchain, huggingface

I'm currently exploring the implementation of Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) for text classification, but I'm facing a lack of comprehensive online resources to guide me through the process.

In this project, the task involves taking a sentence as input and categorizing it into one of three distinct classes. Rather than opting for fine-tuning, I'm keen on leveraging RAG. However, I'm grappling with the challenge of embedding test cases in a manner that allows for subsequent retrieval and classification by a large language model (LLM). I'm specifically looking for an embedding model that can create these embeddings while incorporating the associated class information for each sentence.